# Changing the results shown to user in a quiz with images

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm making a personality quiz, and the user chooses between answers that all have different point values that contribute to their score. Their score changes the results and tells them about their personality. For the results, I want to display a little message along with an image. The image should change depending on their score. My issue is no matter what score I put in, the user only will see the first possible result. I added `console.logs` to check to see if their score is being counted, and it is. I feel I'm close, but I'm definitely missing something...

```
function computeAnswers(){
    var score = 0;
    var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");

    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
        if (answers[i].checked){
            if (answers[i].value === "groot"){
                score += 1;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "starlord"){
                score += 2;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "rocket"){
                score += 3;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "gamora"){
                score += 4;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "drax"){
                score += 5;
            }
            else{
                console.log("This function's facked");
            }
        }
    }


    var groot = new Image();
    groot.src = "groot.jpg";
    var starLord = new Image();
    starLord.src = "starlord.jpg";
    var rocket = new Image();
    rocket.src = "rocket.jpg"
    var gamora = new Image();
    gamora.src = "gamora.jpg"
    var drax = new Image();
    drax.src = "drax.jpg"

    if(score >= 0 <= 10){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are groot!";
        document.body.appendChild(groot);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 11 <= 20){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "I've heard of you! You're Star-Lord!";
        document.body.appendChild(starLord);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 21 <= 30){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You're Rocket! And don't forget it!";
        document.body.appendChild(rocket);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 31 <= 40){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are the beautiful and deadly assassin Gamora!";
        document.body.appendChild(gamora);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 41 <= 50){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are the fearsome warrior Drax The Destroyer!";
        document.body.appendChild(drax);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else{
        console.log("This function is also facked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change if(score >= 0 <= 10) to if(score >= 0 && score <= 10)

Comment: That helped fix the problem! Thanks jeff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's in your if statements re the score. Are you actually getting the correct message with the above coding, but just not the image? Or do you not get either?

For example, in your first one, what happens if you change:

```
if(score >= 0 <= 10){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are groot!";
        document.body.appendChild(groot);
        console.log(score);
    }
```

to

```
if(score <= 10){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are groot!";
        document.body.appendChild(groot);
        console.log(score);
    }
```

If that solves the problem then changing all of them should do it. Of course you'd then need to change them appropriately to suit the value you want.

Comment: Your help along with jeff's from the comments helped. I added the `&&` to the if statements and that solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ocaqveaf/) help.

As @jeff says, you have to change `score >= 0 <= 10` to `score >= 0 && score <= 10`:

```
function computeAnswers(){
    var score = 0;
    var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
    answers = [
        {
            checked:  true,
            value: 'drax'
        },
        {
            checked:  true,
            value: 'drax'
        },
        {
            checked:  true,
            value: 'gamora'
        },
        {
            checked:  true,
            value: 'drax'
        }
    ];

    for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++){
        if (answers[i].checked){
            if (answers[i].value === "groot"){
                score += 1;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "starlord"){
                score += 2;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "rocket"){
                score += 3;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "gamora"){
                score += 4;
            }
            else if(answers[i].value === "drax"){
                score += 5;
            }
            else{
                console.log("This function's facked");
            }
        }
    }


    var groot = new Image();
    groot.src = "http://orig04.deviantart.net/2c42/f/2014/224/5/7/i_am_groot___non_animated__by_milkycherry-d7uxumf.png";
    var starLord = new Image();
    starLord.src = "https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_974f79659bbf_128.png";
    var rocket = new Image();
    rocket.src = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pM7y%2BJQOL._SS36_.jpg"
    var gamora = new Image();
    gamora.src = "https://p.dreamwidth.org/657a0566c4c3/-/img.photobucket.com/albums/v28/FamiraD/GotG_1/byfamira_036a.png"
    var drax = new Image();
    drax.src = "http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/jVgAAOSw9r1WAeBC/s-l64.jpg"

    if(score >= 0 && score <= 10){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are groot!";
        document.body.appendChild(groot);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 11 && score <= 20){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "I've heard of you! You're Star-Lord!";
        document.body.appendChild(starLord);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 21 && score <= 30){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You're Rocket! And don't forget it!";
        document.body.appendChild(rocket);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 31 && score <= 40){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are the beautiful and deadly assassin Gamora!";
        document.body.appendChild(gamora);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else if(score >= 41 && score <= 50){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You are the fearsome warrior Drax The Destroyer!";
        document.body.appendChild(drax);
        console.log(score);
    }
    else{
        console.log("This function is also facked");
    }
}
computeAnswers();
```